# Chrome does not prompt user for camera and/or microphone access even in secure context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mediadevices

I have a webpage served via `https` with the following script:

```
const userMediaConstraints = {
    video: true,
    audio: true
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(userMediaConstraints)
    .then(stream => { 
        console.log("Media stream captured.")
    });
```

When I open it in Firefox or Safari, a prompt asking for permission to use camera and microphone appears. But not in Chrome or Opera. There the access is blocked by default and I have to go to site settings and manually allow the access, which is set to Default(ask).

- `window.isSecureContext` is `true`.
- `navigator.permissions.query({name:'camera'})` resolves to `name: "video_capture", onchange: null, state: "prompt"`.

It looks like Chrome and Opera should show prompt, but they do not. I tested it on a different machine with different user that had no prior history with the website with the same result.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe the function `getUserMedia()` should run in response to a user interaction.

Comment: Safari is the new internet explorer (nothing standard works) ... chrome breaks something every second major release - this is why Chrome is excrement that needs to be wiped off the shoe that is the internet

Comment: @Bravo So, Safari is the new internet explorer, and Chrome should be the browsers wiped out of existence.. Eh!!, surely you mean Safari, especially IOS, as from the last time I looked, it still doesn't support push notification.   Apple unfortunately is what's holds back web technologies.   Money reasons of course.. :(

Comment: @Keith - yes Safari is like IE ... IE at least has the dignity to be dead now :p ... but Chrome ... OMFG!!! Every second release breaks something basic!!!

Comment: @Bravo  doesn't leave many options for a browser,  Firefox, eh ->  `Mozilla has dropped support for web apps in Firefox on desktop and said it has no plans to support Progressive Web Apps in the future.`  Big, no, no from me then..

Comment: Oh, I agree @Keith - the fact that Firefox dropped PWA support is a big (mobile) issue - not that mozilla ever got close to getting PWA right anyway - I just wish Chrome wasn't so damned unreliable - it's buggy as heck every second major release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, having video with autoplay attribute in HTML or similar lines on page load in Javascript prevent Chrome from showing the prompt.

HTML that causes this problem:

```
<video autoplay="true"></video>
```

Javascript that causes this problem:

```
localVideo = document.createElement('video');
videoContainer.append(localVideo);
localVideo.setAttribute('id','localVideo');        
localVideo.play();
```

My guess is that the issue has to do with [Chrome autoplay policy](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/). Perhaps, Chrome treats my website as providing bad user experience and blocks the prompt?

I removed `<video>` from HTML and altered Javascript to create a relevant DOM on `getUserMedia`:

```
let localStream = new MediaStream();
let localAudioTrack;
let localVideoTrack;
let localVideo;

const userMediaConstraints = {
    video: true,
    audio: true
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(userMediaConstraints)
    .then(stream => { 
        localAudioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        localAudioTrack.enabled = true;
        localStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);

        localVideoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        localVideoTrack.enabled = true;
        localStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);

        localVideo = document.createElement('video');
        videoContainer.append(localVideo);
        localVideo.setAttribute('id','localVideo');
        localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
        localVideo.muted = true;

        localVideo.play();
    });
```

And now I get the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You've said you've tried Safari, which suggests to me you're on a Mac.

[This issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=958496&can=2&q=component%3ABlink%3EGetUserMedia%20%20os%3DMac%20%20m%3D74&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) on the Chrome issues list fits your description really well. (I got there from [this](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/1191) on the `webrtc/samples` GitHub project.) It comes down to a Mac OS security setting. Quoting [comment #3](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=958496#c3):

> Please check in Mac system preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Microphone, that Chrome is checked.

(In your case since you want video, you'd also probably have to tick the box under Security & Privacy > Privacy > Camera or similar.)